# Realm queries to extract data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have 2 Realm Models:

```
class CourseModel: Object {
    dynamic var coursename = ""
    dynamic var par3field = 0
    dynamic var par4field = 0
    dynamic var par5field = 0

    let scoreModels: List<ScoresModel> = List<ScoresModel>()
    override internal static func primaryKey() -> String? { return "coursename" }
}

class ScoresModel: Object {
    dynamic var dateplayed = ""

    var courseModel: CourseModel? {
        return linkingObjects(CourseModel.self, forProperty: "scoreModels").first
    }
}
```

The app user will first add a new course for which I use CourseModel. As the user plays a course they enter scores for that course, for which I use ScoresModel, hence the primary key 'coursename'.

I query the CourseModel with

```
let realm = try Realm()
let results = realm.objects(CourseModel)
return results
```

and it produces the following result

```
Results<CourseModel> (
    [0] CourseModel {
        coursename = First Course;
        par3field = 4;
        par4field = 10;
        par5field = 4;
        scoreModels = RLMArray <0x797a36d0> (
            [0] ScoresModel {
                dateplayed = Apr 5, 2016; },
            [1] ScoresModel {
                dateplayed = Mar 3, 2016; }
        );
    },
    [1] CourseModel {
        coursename = Second Course;
        par3field = 4;
        par4field = 10;
        par5field = 4;
        scoreModels = RLMArray <0x7a046f40> (
            [0] ScoresModel {
                dateplayed = Apr 5, 2016; }
        );
    }
)
```

The ScoresModel produces a similar result but without the CourseModel data.
The ScoresModel has a lot of data in it, I only showed 'dateplayed' here to keep it short.

My question is this; when I've extracted the data from Realm how can I access a particular field to work with that data, i.e. how do I get the par5field data to do calculations with it, and also the 2nd question how do I get to the scoreModels data, for example 'dateplayed' to list the dates in a table for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a query against Realm, the results are returned in a `Results` object that behaves exactly like an array. So you need to iterate through each object to access the properties you want for each one.

To answer your first question, to access the `par5field` property (From just the first object):

```
let firstObject? = results.first
let par5field = firstObject.par5field
// Do calculations with it
```

For your second question, `scoreModels` is just a standard array object, so you can just insert the values it into a table view as you would a standard `Array` object.

If you wanted to list ALL of the `ScoreModel` objects, regardless of which `CourseModel` objects they belong to, you can perform a Realm query to get them directly.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let results = realm.objects(ScoreModel)
return results
```

Comment: Hi TiM. Thank you for answering. Your reply on the first question only returns the first par5field, how do I change this to access all par5fields? In the results above it returns the 4 associated with 'First Course' but not the 4 in 'Second Course'. My second question above has another part which I don't understand. When performing the query on CourseModel I get scoreModels as another standard array. Question is, how do I access this data from within the query function to manipulate the data?

Comment: My pleasure! Oh okay, you just need to perform a loop through each object in the `Results` object and perform your necessary calculations on it (i.e `for courseModel in results { }` ). Hmm, you can't manipulate the `scoreModels` data directly within a query, but if you want to use that property to further filter your results, you can use Realm's NSPredicate filter feature to do that: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering Good luck!

Comment: I understand that I cannot manipulate the data directly within the query, I think I expressed myself wrong there. For example, in the query above I can get the CourseModel data and work with it like results.sum("par3field")+results.sum("par4field")+results.sum("par5field"). When trying results("dateplayed") I get an error that it doesn't exist in CourseModel, which I kind of knew... How to get to 'dateplayed' from within the query above is the question. Hope I made myself clear?

Comment: When trying results.valueForKey("date played") instead of results("dateplayed")